# Plex Media Server cannot create directory and will not start up. How can I fix it?

Tags: osx-mavericks, plex

Just today I downloaded Plex from the official website (version 0.9.9.12.504-3e7f93c), on an iMac running Mavericks.
When I run the application, it starts up and shows itself in the taskbar and opens up a browser which shows:

```
404 Not Found
http://127.0.0.1:32400/web/setup.html?machineIdentifier=3ac1e0d03e0XXXXX
```

However, the application will then stay on "starting up" forever. 
I checked out the log files and I think I found the culprit. It seems to fail to create the necessary directories. At the top of the logfile, this shows up:

```
WARN - WARNING: Couldn't create directory /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/SiteConfigurations.bundle/Contents/Resources
DEBUG - Adding directory for site configurations: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/SiteConfigurations.bundle/Contents/Resources
DEBUG - The path changed: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/SiteConfigurations.bundle/Contents/Resources.
DEBUG - This corresponds to site configuration map: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/SiteConfigurations.bundle/Contents/Resources (directory: 1)
DEBUG - Adding directory for site configurations: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Site Configurations
DEBUG - The path changed: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Site Configurations.
DEBUG - This corresponds to site configuration map: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Site Configurations (directory: 1)
WARN - Warning: Couldn't check file: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/SiteConfigurations.bundle/Contents/Resources
DEBUG - File /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Site Configurations changed: -1 => 1404763649.
DEBUG - The path changed: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Site Configurations.
DEBUG - This corresponds to site configuration map: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Site Configurations (directory: 1)
```

What is going wrong? How do I give Plex the correct permissions, if that is even the problem?

**EDIT**: The `/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/` folder is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research and fidling around, I did manage to work around this issue. I'm putting this as an answer here, in case other people run into the same problem:

I installed the Plex Media Center on a MacBook running Mavericks as well, and there the installation and first startup ran smooth. I checked the Plugins folder, and it was full of plugins!
So I copied over the `Plug-ins` and `Plugin Support` folder from the MacBook to the iMac and everything is running as expected now.